# HTML/CSS Keep a div at the bottom of the page with changing page height

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering how I can keep a `div` at the bottom of a page. The problem I'm having is that the page height will change when clicking on expandable elements. How can I keep a div at the very bottom of the page with changing height?

I've tried the following without any luck:

- [Make div stay at bottom of page's content all the time even when there are scrollbars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8824831/make-div-stay-at-bottom-of-pages-content-all-the-time-even-when-there-are-scrol)
- [Align DIV to bottom of the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370396/align-div-to-bottom-of-the-page/20370465)

Thanks!

I've tried making a `div` 100% height and then putting the bottom `div`
like so, but that makes the bottom `div` stay in the exact same position

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; 
}

.bottom {
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Comment: You should try updating your question with a bare minimum example of what you have tried in order to duplicate the problem. [mcve]

Comment: @GreenSaber: What have you tried so far ? Provide reproducible example (fiddle/codepen) if any.

Comment: Put your code so I or anyone can identify where is the problem inside the code. so attach HTML, CSS file with a question. Without that no one can help you.

Comment: Show the page URL or the part of code with the divs

Comment: and what is it supposed to scroll once the content exceed 100% of the window's height ? body , wrapper or is the footer meant to be in sight and the content be the scrolling element ? Clarify your question if the duplicate does not meet your issue.